# Modify object DOM before it is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if it is possible to modify an object in a DOM before it has loaded completely. I'm trying to modify the following object:

```
(function (g) {
    var d = document, 
        i, 
        am = d.createElement('script'), 
        h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        aex = {
            "src": "google.com",
            "type": "text/javascript",
            "async": "true",
            "data-vendor": "acs",
            "data-role": "gateway"
        };
        for (var attr in aex) { 
            am.setAttribute(attr,aex[attr]); 
        }
        h.appendChild(am);
        g['acsReady'] = function () {
            var aT = '__acsReady__', 
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0),
                k = setInterval(function () {
                    if (typeof g[aT] === 'function') {
                        clearInterval(k);
                        for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                            g[aT].call(g, function(fn) { 
                                return function() { 
                                    setTimeout(fn, 1) 
                                };
                            }(args[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }, 50);
        };
})(window);
```

to for example change the value of the src property in the above

Answer (score 1):

Javascript execution starts before the page is rendered the first time. The DOM Parser does notify [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), so you can immediately strip elements or modify them as soon as they are added by the parser.

This question has an example for chrome that should get you going:

[Using Mutation Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533580/deleting-dom-elements-before-the-page-is-displayed-to-the-screen-in-a-chrome-ex)